# Use angular 6 to define base-href in index.html

Tags: angular, base-url

I want to define a base-href dynamically using Angular 6.
Since `index.html` is not attached to any component or modules I'm unable to use any kind of angular methods for this.

Is it possible in Angular 6 ?

Thanks.

Comment: You could use plain javascript

Comment: But I have a constants.ts where I have all constants declared.
Is there any way to define through angular ?